# Better approach for fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, optimization, fragmenttransaction

Which is the better approach for fragment transaction in terms of optimization and performance?

**1.**

ParentFragment-

```
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container, ChildFragment.newInstance(arrayList));
    ft.commit();
```

ChildFragment-

```
   public static ChildFragment newInstance(ArrayList<PlanModel> bPlanModels) {
        ChildFragment fragment = new ChildFragment();
        Bundle bundlearrayList = new Bundle();
        bundlearrayList.putSerializable(AppConstant.ARRAYlIST, bPlanModels);
        fragment.setArguments(bundlearrayList);
        return fragment;
    }
```

**2.**

ParentFragment-

```
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container, ChildFragment.newInstance(arrayList));
    ft.commit();
```

ChildFragment-

```
private ArrayList<BrowsePlanModel> bPlanModels;

public ChildFragment(ArrayList<PlanModel> bPlanModels)
{
this.bPlanModels=bPlanModels
}
public static ChildFragment newInstance(ArrayList<PlanModel> bPlanModels) 
{
        ChildFragment fragment = new ChildFragment(bPlanModels);

        return fragment;
}
```

**3.**

ParentFragment-

```
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();.
    ChildFragment fragment = new ChildFragment();
    Bundle bundlearrayList = new Bundle();
    bundlearrayList.putSerializable(AppConstant.ARRAYlIST, bPlanModels);
    fragment.setArguments(bundlearrayList);
    ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All approaches are incorrect. 
In the first one array is stored to bundle as serializable which leads to lack in performance. You should change it to parcelable array.

```
bundlearrayList.putParcelableArrayList(AppConstant.ARRAYlIST, bPlanModels);
```

In this case your list objects have to implement `Parcelable` interface.

Of course the first one could be right, if you put parcelable array instead of serializable, also use builder for more readability:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, ChildFragment.newInstance(arrayList))
    .commit();
```

Second one is completely wrong, because default constructor should be left in the Fragment, otherwise system won't be able to restore its state and throws an exception on attempt. Also if you'll add it, it will be also wrong, because initial arguments won't be restored because them don't present in input bundle.

Third one is bad encapsulated if you tried to fill bundle in the beginning fragment, because filling a bungle is an inner realization.

By the way, in real projects i prefer to encapsulate responsibility of transactions from beginning fragment to a particular `TransactionManager` class. The approach is easy maintained with di frameworks, like dagger2

Comment: I have updated third one..please check it out and let me know in detail why it is bad in comparison to first one

Comment: @AndroidLearner so i guessed right how you fill bundle in the third case. No changes needed)

Comment: in first case before the transaction is being completed we are calling newInstance method where we are initializing bundle..so in that case also bundle is filled in beginning?

Comment: @AndroidLearner not exactly, beginning fragment means like a fragment class from which we start transaction ( your 'ParentFragment' but it isn't exactly 'parent')

Comment: what is the difference in terms of optimzation and performance if we fill bundle in parent fragment  class rather than child fragment method which we are calling from parent class?

Comment: @AndroidLearner as i mention in answer, third way has least encapsulation level, than the first one (starter fragment has responsibility of creating second fragment). They haven't differences in performance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127056/discussion-between-beloo-and-android-learner).

Comment: @AndroidLearner, this answer summarizes most points. The only thing I can add is that you should consider removing `AppConstant.ARRAYlIST` constant - this constant should reside in the "child" fragment itself (and if you go with something similar to approach #1, this constant can be made `private`)